# Thinking Sphinx not accessing local index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx

A rails 3.2.18 with thinking_sphinx 3.1.1 is being passed from development to production mode.
In the process, while any of the following work:

```
bundle exec rake ts:rebuild
bundle exec rake ts:index
bundle exec rake ts:stop
bundle exec rake ts:start
```

searches are ending up with

```
ActionView::Template::Error (unknown local index [...]
```

I initially realised that I hade 2 search pids running on the application because development had a `shared` directory in which the sphinx indicies and tmp/pid file were placed.  That was being carried over and therefore creating two pids: one from within the shared folder, another within the application release's shared folder. Duh!

still a `ps aux | grep searchd`  is returning two processes for
`/fna/shared/config/development.sphinx.conf`
The pids does **not** match that in the shared folder and they call **development**
Another application, still in development (!) also has two processes

1) is it normal to have two processes?
2) how to get the pids to start for the production.shpinx.conf (and get rid of incidental pollution) ?

I realise this may also be impacted by the capistrano deployment and would welcome suggestions to get matters done properly.

**Update**
`ps ax | grep "searchd"` gave proper active pids to

```
kill 99335
```

ran

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake ts:rebuild
[...]
Started searchd successfully (pid: 7086)
```

now two pids are for the proper environment

```
shared/config/production.sphinx.conf
```

and redeployed.  with success.  so the remaining doubt is in capistrano deployment.
Given that indexing is run nightly (and is acceptable as such), should the deploy.rb file include:

```
invoke_command "cd #{release_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake ts:rebuild"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run `ts:rebuild` after every deploy - it's like `db:migrate`, it's only needed when you change the structure of your indices, or add/remove indices. If you just want to update the data *in* the indices, use the `ts:index` task (as you're doing regularly already).

It's worth making sure your [paths are set up correctly](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/deployment.html) to ensure all production Sphinx files are outside of a specific release directory - best to put them in the shared directory or something similar (rather than relying on symlinked files). If this is all set up, then no TS tasks need to be run as part of a deploy.

Also: Thinking Sphinx v3 uses Sphinx's [threaded](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.1.8.html#conf-workers) workers, so there's always at least two processes - one being the master, and one waiting for the first connection. If there are more concurrent connections, then there are more searchd processes.